# Ошибка сборки Qt-проекта при использовании QThread с использованием библиотек PostgreSQL 15 (win)

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, qthread

Прошу помощи в диагностике проблемы:
Есть проект на Qt 5.14.2, который предполагается использовать в мультиплатформенном варианте. Проект рабочий и развивается. Использует прямой доступ к БД PostgreSQL 15 через ее нативные библиотеки.

Возникла необходимость перенести часть кода в параллельный поток используя QThread. При сборке в Linux все работает как предполагается, однако при сборке в Windows выдает массу ошибок не связанных с кодом самой программы (или связанных, но неявно).

Проблема начинается при попытке включить

```
 #include <QThread>
```

. Компилятор выдает массу ошибок типа :

> C:\Qt\Qt5.14.2\Tools\mingw730_64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.3.0\include\c++\thread:276:
> ошибка: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are
> 'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' and
> 'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}') In file
> included from
> C:/Qt/Qt5.14.2/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/future:39:0,
> from C:/Qt/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/mingw73_64/include/QtCore/qthread.h:50,
> from C:/Qt/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/mingw73_64/include/QtCore/QThread:1,
> from C:\Design\Qt....\src.cpp:3:
> C:/Qt/Qt5.14.2/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:
> In function 'bool std::operator==(std::thread::id, std::thread::id)':
> C:/Qt/Qt5.14.2/Tools/mingw730_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/thread:276:26:
> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are
> 'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' and
> 'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}')
> return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Гугл подсказывает, что возможно проблема в модели потоков, компилятор имеет POSIX модель, а какая у PostgreSQL 15 (win-64) я не нашел.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным и есть ли решение или посмотреть куда? Ссылка сойдет за ответ, читать умею. ))

Спасибо.

PS. Да, примерчик. Извините. Ничего особо умного, просто по документации:

есть объект, который должен загружать таблицу БД в фоне (таблица большая, критика типа "а зачем так делать" не относится к делу, так надо по условиям задачи). Заголовок:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QUuid>
#include <QQueue>
/// Первоначальная мультипоточная загрузка сообщений
class clsLoader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    clsLoader(QVector<data*> *reciver = nullptr);

  public slots:
    void doLoad();

  private:
    QVector<data*> *recs;

 signals:
    void send(int count, int curr);
};
```

есть класс, который инициализирует загрузку:

```
class Datas : public BaseTable
{
   Q_OBJECT
  public:
...
  private:
    QThread * load_thread;
    clsLoader * mtLoader;

  private slots:
    void update(int count, int curr);
};
```

В заголовке не приходится включать

```
 #include <QThread>
```

Все определения находятся сами, хотя я и не понимаю как. В том же окне используется и реализация splashscreen, так что может быть и в этом дело, но почему тогда компилятор не видит нужных определений QThread в cpp - мне не понятно.

Зато приходится в .cpp

```
#include <QThread>
/// При создании экземпляра класса автоматически считываем всё содержимое таблицы в собственный массив
Datas::Datas(QSplashScreen *splash) :BaseTable()
{
    load_thread = new QThread();
    mtLoader = new clsLoader(&DataList);
    mtLoader->moveToThread(load_thread);
    connect(mtLoader, SIGNAL(send(int, int)), this, SLOT(update(int, int)));
    connect(load_thread, SIGNAL(started()), mtLoader, SLOT(doLoad()));
    load_thread->start();

    return;
}
```

Как только я включаю указанную строку - при сборке вываливает указанную выше ошибку (-и) их там куча, привел в пример только первую.

Повторюсь, что ИМЕННО этот код при сборке под Linux Mint собирается без проблем и работает как ожидалось. При сборке под Win 10 x64 - не собирается. Проект использует подключение к PostgreSQL 15 x64 под win в Linux x64 но вроде 14 версия. Подключение в cmake:

Win:

```
target_link_libraries(prg PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Charts libpq )
```

Linux:

```
 target_link_libraries(prg PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Charts pq )
```

**UPD 1:** Смена платформы на Qt 5.15.2. не дало положительного результата.
Используемый компилятор:

```
gcc -v                                                                             Using built-in specs.                                                                                                   
...
**Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32**                                                                                              
...
**Thread model: posix**                                                                                                     gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

**UPD 2:**
Перевел проект на сборку под MS VC 2022 - проблема решилась. В чем конкретно был косяк так и не понял. Использую для сборки (под Windows) Qt 5.15.2 собранную для компилятора Microsoft - все работает (ну не считая собственных ошибок). Вывод: совместимость MinGW компилятора оставляет желать лучшего. Так что комментаторы внизу были правы, хотя и очень обидно.

Comment: Попробуйте собрать компилятором студии

Comment: Какой-никакой минимальный примерчик бы

Comment: комментируйте файл кусками, пока не найдёте, в windows.h и производных встречаются неожиданные #define, например `small`

Comment: Какой файл комментировать? Тут и так десяток строк. Или вы предлагаете комментировать системные заголовки? :)

Comment: ну, у вас судя по всему определения находятся через precompiled headers, в qt обычно их кладут в stable.h, там возможно проблема

Comment: Как я говорил - в линухе все работает. Хотя там компилятор 11 версии (не путать со стандартом С 11) супротив 7.х в винде. Не помогла даже смена на Qt 5.15.2 и mingw 8.4 (в линухе 5.15.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению пришлось для сборки под Windows использовать компилятор MS VC 2022 и, соответственно, сборку Qt для него же... увы. Может в дальнейшем что-то и выясниться, но нет времени вникать что именно не так.

Comment: проект hellowindow из examples нормально собирается qt5.14.2+mingw7.30 для x64

Answer (score 0):

В общем и целом ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847804/stdthread-works-in-cygwin-but-not-in-mingw)

Для использования `std::thread` вам нужен mingw с поддержкой posix thread (Вполне возможно что сойдет мелкомягкий компилер)

Comment: Увы... использую mingw c++: C:\Qt\Qt5.15.2\Tools\mingw810_64\bin>gcc -v                                                                             Using built-in specs.                                                                                                   ...        Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32   Thread model: posix                                                                                                     gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

Comment: Все равно спасибо за наводку, буду курить гугл дальше... Возможно потребуется переступить через свою лень и собрать Qt вручную. Сейчас более новая версия gcc 13.1 вот ей и буду собирать. Компилятор мелкомягких - это крайний случай.

Comment: @Ingvar, еще можете попробовать установить msys2 - там есть свои сборки gcc, qt и postgresql - по идее, они должны дружить между собой, если устанавливать всех одной архитектуры.